# How to find if DNS host & DNS resolution are enabled or not in Amazon VPC

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc

I want to find if **DNS host** & **DNS resolution** are enabled or not in Amazon VPC in .net

For this, I am using Amazon EC2 SDK and trying to find the VPC attributes which has both properties but it seems that whatever property I am setting in request parameter, that property is set to true and another one is set to false.

```
DescribeVpcAttributeRequest describeVpcAttributeRequest = new DescribeVpcAttributeRequest()
{
    VpcId = "vpc-********",
    Attribute = VpcAttributeName.EnableDnsSupport
};
DescribeVpcAttributeResponse describeVpcAttributeResponse = await ec2Client.DescribeVpcAttributeAsync(describeVpcAttributeRequest);
```

Here I want to find both of the properties `DnsSupport` & `DnsHostnames` if they are enabled or not for the given VPC Id but in a request, we are required to provide Attribute value from one of the mentioned properties. Once it runs, it sets the specified attribute to true and another one to false, so it is not behaving as it should do.

Can anybody please let me know if there is a way to find those 2 properties without setting them or specifying them in any attribute?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The Describe calls _do not_ change values of attributes. If this happened for you, please edit your question to show us how you have determined that the values changed, and that it was a result of the Describe calls so that we can reproduce the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Java person, so I did the following with the AWS CLI (which makes the same API calls):

```
$ aws ec2 describe-vpc-attribute --attribute enableDnsSupport --vpc-id vpc-1234

{
    "VpcId": "vpc-1234",
    "EnableDnsSupport": {
        "Value": true
    }
}

$ aws ec2 describe-vpc-attribute --attribute enableDnsHostnames --vpc-id vpc-1234
{
    "VpcId": "vpc-1234",
    "EnableDnsHostnames": {
        "Value": true
    }
}
```

The Describe calls *do not* change values of the attributes.